# How do you, using a set of random given letters, check if a word is created with only those given letters

Tags: java, string

In Java, I am supposed to make a word game where one is supposed to make letters with a given set of random letters. I have already wrote the code to find the letters (Variable is `String Letters` ), but I am having trouble checking if the word chosen by the player (`String word`), is actually created using the given letters? I have a txt file of all the English words in the English language, and this is what I am basing it off if it is a word. How do I do this? I am pretty sure it has something to do with checking the index, or using the built in command contains at.

I have already tried to search for this. However other questions used C-Language or Python. I have found 1 Java explanation, however I am new to coding and do not understand the code and variables they used.

This is an example of where I need help

```
            if (Words.contains(letters) == true) {
            System.out.println("That is a word");
            for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
                int index = letters.indexOf(word.charAt(i));

            }
```

Full method.

```
  public static void getWord(String letters) {
    int trys = 0;
    int trysLeft = 5;
    System.out.println("Input a word that you can make with those letters");


    while (trys < 5) {
        String word = getString(); //getString is a method where user can input a desired string

        if (Words.contains(letters) == true) {
            System.out.println("That is a word");
            for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
                int index = letters.indexOf(word.charAt(i));

            }
        }
        else if (Words.contains(word) == false) {
            System.out.println("That is not a real word! Please enter a word that you can make with these letters.");
            trys++;
            trysLeft=trysLeft-trys;
            System.out.println("You have " + trysLeft + " trys Left. Keep at it!");
        }
        else if (Words.contains(letters) == false) {
            System.out.println("You can not make a word with these letters.");
            trys++;
            trysLeft=trysLeft-trys;
            System.out.println("You have " + trysLeft + " trys Left. Keep at it!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: contains won't work as is because it "Returns true if and only if the string contains the specified sequence of char values."  But your letters might be scrambled from what I understand

Comment: @jwils Yes they are in a random sequence. This is because the project specifications are that the letters have to be random, so any letter a-z can be picked (it is a pool of 7 letters)

Comment: I'm unclear exactly what help you need.  If you're asking us to explain this code, then you should spend some time in your favourite debugger.  If you're asking us for help with your own solution, you will need to clarify exactly what help you need.

Comment: @JoeC Ok, so say the random letters I get are " A R I Q F T", I can make the word "fair" because it is in the English language ( I forgot to add in the post that the words the player is trying to make from the given random letters are supposed to be words in the English language), but I can also enter "Eye" in the NetBeans IDE, and it still counts it as a word, even though the letters in Eye are not part of the given random set of letters. How can I make it where "Eye" is not accepted, which is what I am trying to do in the else statement that says ` You can not make a word with these letters'

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the cointains for each letter. If you send a charSeq, example { 'a' , 'b', 'd' }, java will try to find if your string contains completely "abd"

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to sort the letters in your letter list and your word and see if your word is contains in the available letters, like this:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String letters = sort("haat");
    System.out.println("Is a word: " + letters.contains(sort("hat")));
}

public static String sort(String s)
{
    char[] chars = s.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(chars);
    return new String(chars);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many techniques that you could use to implement this class project.
Here is one:

1. Build a `Map` from the input letters.  The key of the map should be a Character and the Value of the map should be the count of letters.
2. Build a `Map` from the word guess.  Again, the key of the map should be a Character and the Value of the map should be the count of letters.
3. Compare the maps.  If they are equal, then the word is constructed from exactly the letters in the input letters string.